# Showing Android apps in multiple categories

Tags: android

In Google play I have observed some apps in multiple categories, I mean single app in two categories(photography and live wallpaper). How is it possible to get app into both photography and live wallpaper?

Answer (score 3):

This is because Google Play has subcategories. For example, a stock broking app may be listed in the Finance category but not in the Mobile Banking or Insurance category. These are handpicked categories by Google and they constantly A/B test (aka give new apps a chance). If users in the real world who are browsing the category are clicking and installing apps that are newly displayed, then these apps tend to retain their rank in the subcategories.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that, app can have only one category. If you've seen the same app in multiple categories, the most simple explanation I can imagine is that these were different apps.

Comment: Package name is same for both the apps in two categories, so I think it's single app.

Comment: I too observed a number of apps appear in both category searches. Same package name, and same category when you actually view the details. How is this achieved ?

Comment: I've also see the same app ranking for different categories